# PFE "convergence"

Tags: derivatives, counterparty-risk, exposure

I'm studying Counterparty Credit Risk. I was reading about Potential Future Exposure (PFE) and I've seen a lot of examples and graphs about how the PFE behaves (as the time horizon increases) for different derivatives. In practice, I understand you have a bunch of derivatives traded with the counterparty A. So, if you want to compute the PFE over a time horizon lets say of 50 years, you have to consider all the derivatives traded with that counterparty, and project the risk factors (prices, rate curves, etc) over the time horizon (via Montecarlo) to price all the derivatives and then choose some confidence level (95-99) to keep that pricing and say your PFE is: 5 mill tomorrow, 6 mill in one week, ... 18 mill in 50 years, etc.

So I understand that this PFE will be different when comparing counterparty A with counterparty B. But I want to know if there exists an article or some theorem that states the PFEs for counterparty A and B will "look alike" or will converge to some curve, random variable or stochastic process as the quantity of derivatives increases. Some "convergence" theorem maybe?

I know that this may not make any sense or might depend on the model used to simulate the stocks, discount curves, etc. but if there is or there isn't such theorem I would appreciate you could help me.